# ReactJS, create-react-app gets an error

Tags: reactjs, cmd, create-react-app

I run from my console the "create-react-app practise1" command but it gets an error.
I couldn't understand why. Can you help me?
Normally I used it before as "create-react-app react-complete-guide" and this command had worked at that time.
I share all the codes that i get as screenshot.

Thank you,

[My Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvW58.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem directly with `create-react-app` itself but one of it's dependencies it needs, `require-from-string`. And that issue is coming from the npm registry itself, and *temporarily*, not `create-react-app`. See [this](https://status.npmjs.org/) about the npm registry status and [this issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/3701) from create-react-app itself:

What you can do, is if you have another project bootstrapped with `create-react-app`, you can copy it and make changes as neccessary for starting a new project. Or - you can wait until this issue from the npm registry is resolved. This is what happens when modern projects take a large number of dependencies - if a few of those dependencies aren't available, the whole project can have problems.

Comment: You were right, It was about npm and it is solved anymore.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have text like this in your error:

```
error Received malformed response from registry for "timed-out". The 
registry may be down.
```

Currently part of NPM is down. https://status.npmjs.org/

> Identified - Several packages including "require-from-string" are currently unavailable. We are aware of the issue and are working to restore the affected user and packages. Please do not attempt to republish packages, as this will hinder our progress in restoring them. 
>   Jan 6, 19:45 UTC